# How to stop dhclient from updating resolvconf on Debian?

Tags: dns, dhcp, resolv.conf, dhclient, resolvconf

I want to use certain DNS servers on my Debian, regardless of whatever I get through DHCP. I'm trying to configure dhclient to ignore those, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Per advice from [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/) I added `supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;` stanza to my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file. I also tried [these answers from superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/507461/272925) and removed `domain-name-servers` and `domain-search` values from `request` directive. Both of those, applied separately as well as together, seem to have no effect. After running `sudo dhclient -r` and then `sudo dhclient`, I still find following entries in `/etc/resolvconf/run/interfaces/enp2s0.dhclient`:

```
domain lan
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

which prompt `resolvconf` to put `nameserver 192.168.1.1` in my `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

I double-checked if I don't miss any semicolons or similar syntax elements. How can I get my configuration to work? **I don't want to remove resolvconf**, since it manages changes in my nameservers when I use corporate VPN and it does it well. It looks like dhclient is the offending party here.

Here's my current `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` with default comments removed for the sake of clarity:

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

#supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

Update: per request in comment, here's output of `ps ax | grep dhcp`:

```
23528 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep dhcp
```

Comment: Please add `ps ax | grep dhcp` to the post.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro edited in.

Comment: my fault...please change it to `ps ax | grep dhc`. Also do include `cat /etc/network/interfaces`, or at least the configuration of the relevant interface for this discussion.

Comment: Have you commented out too the domain-name-servers from the require directive after the request line you show us?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need `resolvconf` to manage your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, the simplest solution is to uninstall `resolvconf` entirely.

Comment: +1. `apt-get purge --kill-kill-kill --burn-it-with-fire resolvconf`.

Comment: I'd like to avoid that, since resolvconf automatizes nameservers change when connecting to VPN and disconnecting from it. I should probably add that information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> How to stop dhclient from updating resolvconf on Debian?
>
> I don't want to remove resolvconf

You need to add `domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` to

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

And

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

Regenerate `resolv.conf` then restart networking:

```
resolvconf -u
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, resolvconf is not the problem. My solution for this was to create a file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/ignore_resolv_conf` and put this in it:

```
# prevent dhclient from touching /etc/resolv.conf
make_resolv_conf() { : ; }
```

Make sure the file is executable.

Setting options in the DHCP client to ignore resolvers doesn't make it ignore resolvers.

This works for me on Ubuntu 20.04, YMMV.

Comment: Great answer, works on Debian 11 too.

Answer (score 0):

Write protect your `/etc/resolv.conf` file using the `chattr` command on a Linux bases system.

The syntax is:

```
# chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

The `+i` option (attribute) write protects `/etc/resolv.conf` file on Linux so that no one can modify it including **root** user.

Comment: This is a brute force "solution" and makes it even harder to understand how the different component work together eventually. Here is a nice list of what accesses resolv.conf https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527581/88177

Comment: @user640916 Sometimes there is no time for understanding how those components work together. Especially when the way they works changes every year.

Comment: end this can speed up finding what accesses the file since daemon usually leaves logs